# 翻訳に疑問：コメントの通報理由「くだけすぎ」「廃止された」

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳, モデレーション

英語版SOで言うところの "too chatty" がここでは「くだけすぎ」と訳されていますが・・・

[A guide to moderating comments - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237980/286934)

> **too chatty** comments might be polite, friendly, even informative - but they have nothing whatsoever to do with the post! Whether tangential discussions or simply two friends chewing the fat, these are pretty benign - right up until they're being shoved in the face of every reader two years later. Again, don't worry too much about these if you don't see them by default.

くだけすぎというより、質問や回答に関係のない「雑談」「世間話」といった意味合いに見えます。

上記に該当しない「くだけすぎ」は「失礼または不快」「建設的でない」で概ねカバーできるように思うので、 "too chatty" の訳は「質問や回答に関係のないおしゃべり」とでもするのはいかがでしょうか？

ついでに、"obsolete" が「廃止された」と訳されていたので、「既に必要とされていない」にしようかと。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Transifex 上で訳を変更しました](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40286069?comment=%2Fq%2F1901%2F)。近日中にサイトにも反映されると思います。

Comment: サイトのDBに適用しました。次回のビルドにサイトへ適用になりますので、数時間お待ちください。

Comment: @jmac ヘルプセンターの記事も修正をお願いできますか？ http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging